# Configuration values for azure function app environment

Tags: azure, function, environment

You are developing an Azure Function App. You develop code by using a language that is not supported by the Azure Function App host. The code language supports HTTP primitives.
You must deploy the code to a production Azure Function App environment.
You need to configure the app for deployment.
Which configuration values should you use?

please advise whether it should be
Code -> Custom Handler -> custom
or
Docker container -> power shell core -> 7.0

tried Docker container -> power shell core -> 7.0 but did not work

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Custom Handler refer this [**Github sample**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-custom-handlers):-

***Sample Http Golang Custom handler:-***

Reference [**here**](https://github.com/groovy-sky/azure-func-go-handler#azure-functions-custom-handler-in-go).

**`GoCustomHandler.go:-`**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func httpTriggerHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For") != "" {
        w.Write([]byte(strings.Split(r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For"),":")[0]))
    } else if r.Header.Get("Host") != "" {
        w.Write([]byte(strings.Split(r.Header.Get("Host"),":")[0]))
    } else if r.RemoteAddr != "" {
        w.Write([]byte(strings.Split(r.RemoteAddr,":")[0]))
    }
}

func main() {
    httpInvokerPort, exists := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_HTTPWORKER_PORT")
    if exists {
        fmt.Println("FUNCTIONS_HTTPWORKER_PORT: " + httpInvokerPort)
    }
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/httptrigger", httpTriggerHandler)
    log.Println("Go server Listening...on httpInvokerPort:", httpInvokerPort)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+httpInvokerPort, mux))
}
```

***Built this code with the command below:-***

```bash
go build GoCustomHandler.go
```

`GoCustomHandler.exe` will be created and then add it in the `host.json` like below:-

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    },
    "customHandler": {
        "description": {
            "defaultExecutablePath": "GoCustomHandler.exe",
            "workingDirectory": "",
            "arguments": []
        },
        "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
    }

}
```

As you have already tried using **`Powershell core`**, Directly create a Http Trigger and tweak it for Http Primitive use case like below:-

**`run.ps1:-`**

```
# Azure Function PowerShell Script for HTTP Trigger

param($req, $TriggerMetadata)

# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $req.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    if ($req.Body) {
        $reqBody = $req.Body | ConvertFrom-Json
        $name = $reqBody.Name
    }
}

# Prepare the response body
if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
} else {
    $body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
}

# Create a response object using HTTP primitives
$response = [System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage]::new([System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::OK)
$responseContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($body)
$response.Content = $responseContent

# Return the response
$response
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**function.json:-**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["get", "post"]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```